# tf.cast() causes my program to fail back propagation, how can I solve this problem?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

A  = tf.constant([[1,7,3]],dtype=tf.float32)
B = tf.zeros_like([[1,0,0],[0,1,0]])
C = tf.cast(A,dtype=tf.int32)+B

f = tf.gradients(C,A)
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(f))
```

I am using tensorflow 2.3.0 version. When running this program, an error will be prompted:

```
TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type <class 'NoneType'>
```

How can I complete data conversion in tensorflow without hindering back propagation?Initially, A is a float type and B is an int type, this cannot be changed.

Answer (score 0):

[Tensorflow does not differentiate through integers](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/autodiff#3_took_gradients_through_an_integer_or_string). Cast your int to float instead.

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

A  = tf.constant([[1,7,3]],dtype=tf.float32)
B = tf.zeros_like([[1,0,0],[0,1,0]])
C = A+tf.cast(B,tf.float32)

f = tf.gradients(C,A)
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(f))
```

Results in :

```
[array([[2., 2., 2.]], dtype=float32)]
```

Comment: I know what you mean. When deriving A, convert B to the same type as A, but my actual needs are a bit different from the example. I need to derive A and B at the same time, so this method is not applicable.

Comment: Tensorflow does not differentiate through integers. You **can't get a gradient** on B if B is an integer. I am not converting them to the same type, I am casting them in **float**. You are saying that you can't change the type of B, then you can't differentiate in regards to B with TensorFlow.